# Hacer suma del array en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, recursión

Implementar la función countArray: a partir de un array en el cual cada posición puede ser un único número u otro array anidado de números, determinar la suma de todos los números contenidos en el array. El array será recibido por parámetro.
//Utilizar el método Array.isArray() para determinar si algún elemento de array es un array anidado

```
var countArray = function(array) {
    var suma = 0;

    if (array.length === 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            countArray(array[i])
        }
        return countArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Te falta ir sumando los valores y retornar la variable suma que creaste

Comment: Para sumar los valores debo crear otro for?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar `Array.reduce()` para evitar hacer un `for`. Te dejo un ejemplo y esta es [la documentación oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce)

```js
const sumarArreglo = ( arr ) => {
  return arr.reduce( (a,b) => {
    const newB = Array.isArray( b ) ? sumarArreglo( b ) : b;
    return a + newB;
  }, 0);
}

const myArr = [ 1,2,3, [1,2,3], 5, [5,5] ];

console.log( sumarArreglo( myArr ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que ir sumando el valor de cada elemento en la variable `suma`, teniendo en cuenta que si el elemento es un array en sí mismo, tienes que hacer la llamada recursiva. Algo así:

```
var countArray = function(array) {
    var suma = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            suma += countArray(array[i]);
        } else {
            suma += array[i];
        }
    }
    return suma;
}
```

Nota. La comprobación

```
if (array.length === 0) {
    return 0;
}
```

no es necesaria. Si el array está vacío, nunca se entra en el bucle y la función retorna el valor de inicialización de `suma`, es decir, `0`