# Devolver sumatorio de enteros de una lista

Tags: javascript

en Javascript estoy creando esta función que recibe un arreglo de enteros `numeros`, y debe devolver la suma de todos los enteros, pero no sé lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Este es mi código:

```js
function agregarNumeros(numeros) {
   var sumatoria = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
     sumatoria = i + i++;
   }
    return sumatoria;
}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, quizá esta respuesta a otra pregunta te ayude: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/374295/111983

Comment: Por cierto, dentro del for, lo que tienes que hacer es sumar los valores de numeros, pero lo que estas haciendo es sumar el índice que estás recorriendo. O sea, dentro del for tendrías que poner esto `sumatoria += numeros[i];` Y ya está.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varios errores en tu código:

- En cada iteración, a `sumatoria` le estás asignando el valor de `i` y de `i++`, que es `i + 1`.
- `sumatoria`, aunque su nombre parece indicar otra cosa, no va *acumulando* nada, al terminar va a tener el valor de la última suma de `i + i + 1`
- estás incrementando el valor de `i` dentro del cuerpo del ciclo, al llamar a `i++` justo en la expresión `sumatoria = i + i++;`. `i++` es como hacer `i = i + 1`,
- Incrementas el vlaor de `i` también como parte del iterador (en la última parte del `for`), de manera que en cada iteracion `i` se incrementa en `2` (y no en `1` que es lo usual).

La idea del ciclo `for`, como se ve en tu código (y como lo necesitas para recorrer el arreglo) es ir incrementando `i` de uno en uno en cada iteración, y en la variable `sumatoria` ir *acumulando* el valor de los elementos del arreglo.

Esto se traduce en:

```
sumatoria = sumatoria + numeros[i];
```

Que se puede leer: a `sumatoria` le asignamos el valor de `sumatoria` mas el `i`esimo elemento del arreglo `numeros`.

Otra forma de expresar esto es con:

```
sumatoria += numeros[i];
```

En resumen, este código si hace la sumatoria:

```js
function sumarNumeros(numeros) {
   var sumatoria = 0;
   for(var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++){
     sumatoria += numeros[i];
   }
    return sumatoria;
}

console.log(sumarNumeros([1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar el método [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para ejecutar una función en cada elemento del array, y devolver un solo valor.

El método reduce recibe un parámetro que es una función, y esa función recibe una variable acumuladora, y el valor actual por el que se está iterando. Opcionalmente también puede recibir el índice del valor actual y el array original.

Así que esto funcionará:

```js
function sumatorio(acumulador, valorActual) {
  return acumulador + valorActual;
}

const myArr = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2 ];
const resultado = myArr.reduce(sumatorio);

console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: La respuesta parece correcta (+1), pero la verdad para una pregunta que muestra que el OP tiene in nivel tan básico encuentro que es mejor una respuesta que use técnicas más elementales; así el OP puede ver como funciona el acceso a arrays a nivel principiante.

Comment: @SJuan76 entiendo lo que dices, y puede que tengas razón, pero creo que una respuesta así puede ayudar a más personas. Además, los arrays tienen muchos métodos que permiten hacer muchas cosas, creo que es bueno familiarizarse con ellos.